# How to change button if edit text is not empty?

Tags: java, android

I did a timer that the user has 45 seconds to type the SMS.If he starts typing the button  should change to enable and change text to "Validate SMS".
If the time has expired it should give the option to send the SMS again.So the button should change to enabled and text should change to "Send again" like the other time but for a different function.

How can i make this so that i don't have a conflict between the two states of a button(Validade and send again)?.The way my code is working right now is that if the user starts typing and hit the button the timer resets and that should never happen.When the user types the button should be enabled but when the user clicks the sms should be validate and not go for the other function.

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_forgot_password);
       
        t1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.t1);
        b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        sms = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EditTextSMS);



        

        mCountDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(45000, 1000) {

            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

                sms.addTextChangedListener(loginTextWatcher);
                t1.setText("00:" + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
                if(millisUntilFinished<=10000){
                    t1.setText("00:0" + millisUntilFinished / 1000);

                }
            }

            public void onFinish() {
                t1.setText("Time is over");
                b1.setEnabled(true);

            }
        }.start();


        b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mCountDownTimer.start();
            }
        });











    }

    private TextWatcher loginTextWatcher = new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
            String smsInput = sms.getText().toString().trim();

            b1.setEnabled(!smsInput.isEmpty() );

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

        }
    };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a new button named "Try Again". When the "Retry" status happens, you can make the visibilty state visible.
The first situation must of course be "**gone**" and you have to be careful that you position it in the correct coordinates.
Finally, you can continue with your listener.